# Using Drupal for a portion of my site

Tags: drupal, hosting

I have a domain hosted on Godaddy VPS, Would it be possible to have drupal manage only a portion of my website?

Example:
site.com/* <-- regular html&css

site.com/drupal/* <---all drupal stuff

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run drupal site from sub-folder:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2457415

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to install Drupal on sub folder or sub domain too. First, you need to create sub-domain OR sub folder on your website where you want to build Drupal. After that, you can install it..you can find [drupal installation guide from here..](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install)